# Изменение строки подключения в проекте с гитхаба при работе с локальной базой данных

Tags: c#, база-данных

У меня есть два похожих друг на друга примера со схожей проблемой, сначала опишу примеры:

*1 пример.* Pet-проект на гитхабе. Допустим я сделал какой-то проект для себя на WPF/ASP.NET, в котором работал с базой данных локально. Потом решил выложить этот проект и дамп базы данных на гитхаб, чтобы любой пользователь смог скачать программу к себе на пк и пользоваться ей.

*2 пример.* Выполнение тестового задания. Допустим работодатель из IT-компании дал мне тестовое задание, в котором я должен сделать приложение, работающее с базой данных. Опять же, я выложил на гитхаб решение и дамп базы данных, чтобы работодатель смог проверить выполнение задания.

Сама **проблема** - и в первом, и во втором случае у меня была локальная база данных, а значит в файле конфигурации была примерно такая строка подключения:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "connStr": "Server=localhost;
    Port=5432;Database=databasename;
    Username=postgres;Password=admin"
  }
```

или такая:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
        Initial Catalog=databasename;
        Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

(тут 2 разных проекта, в первом работа с postgresql, во втором с sql server)

Итак, вопрос - как пользователю (в первом примере) и работодателю (во втором примере) использовать моё приложение? До этого вопроса я писал в ридми файле репозитория на гитхабе что-то типо "скачайте проект, восстановите базу данных из дампа, поменяйте в файле конфигурации строку подключения к базе данных".

Окей, понятно, что раз база данных не находится на сервере её в любом случае придется восстанавливать из дампа.
Но можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы пользователям моего приложения не приходилось менять строку подключения на свою? (Ведь в любом случае это придется делать, если, например, у них другой порт, пароль, юзернейм и т.д).
Или это решается только переносом бд на сервер, а если бд развернута локально, то надо делать так, как делаю я?

Comment: `её в любом случае придется восстанавливать из дампа` - для таких целей существуют миграции, где вы можете, например при первом запуске проекта восстановить базу данных при помощи кода (допустим метод [.Migrate()](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.migrate) от EF). Что касается подключения - если это Pet проект, или просто проект для показа неких навыков, то смысл использования полноценных БД? Берите SQLite или аналоги. Ну а если база полноценная, то документация ваше все. Если проект с UI, то можете сделать окно конекта

Comment: @EvgeniyZ насколько я понимаю миграции это именно структура базы данных (ну то есть какие таблицы, например, в ней есть), а что если нужно, чтобы база данных уже была заполнена какими-то данными? тут я так понимаю миграции не помогут. `смысл использовать полноценные бд`, в целом соглашусь, но во-первых это опыт работы с конкретной субд, а во-вторых в тестовом задании может быть прописан стек (собственно так у меня и было, нужно было использовать именно постгрес). Окно конекта возьму на вооружение, а вот про документацию не совсем понял, что именно там искать?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а нет, кажется я ошибаюсь, в миграциях вроде как можно использовать не только `create table`, но и `insert` операции

Comment: Скажем так, если вы делаете проект для людей, то надо понимать для кого конкретно делается проект. Если, например для бухгалтеров или еще кого, без опыта IT, то вы должны облегчить этот процесс (окно подключения к базе, а не конфиг), если OpenSource проект, или проект для IT сектора, то напишите документацию о том, как настроить базу. Если это для работодателя, то я считаю, что он сам разберется как настроить подключение к базе, его будет интересовать другие аспекты проекта. Ну а если это просто Пет проект, то ему и база не нужна, SQLite достаточно. Миграция - да, структура, но и данные можно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо большое за ответ, просто думал что восстанавливать бд из дампа, а потом ещё и менять строку подключения как-то слишком сложно для пользователя и это можно сделать проще, ну в целом так и оказалось)